# How to animate specific container inside a list

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to animate and change the container height from 60 to 120 for example, 
And change the container content(image fill half of the container when expanded) when the user press on the icon.

Any ideas how to do it? Doesn't work for me with simple

```
setState(() {
  height = 120; 
 });
```

My code:

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 20,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return _buildCard(context, index);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCard(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0, vertical: 8.0),
      child: Container(
          color: Colors.teal,
          height: 60.0,
          width: 60.0,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(12.0),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12.0),
                ),
                child: Image.network(
                  "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/08/29/06/24/elephants-4438284__340.jpg",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                onPressed: () {

                },
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AnimatedContainer()` -

Code:

```
double _height = 60.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.edit),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _height = 120;
            });
          }),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 20,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return _buildCard(context, index);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCard(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0, vertical: 8.0),
      child: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
          color: Colors.teal,
          height: _height,
          width: 60.0,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(12.0),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12.0),
                ),
                child: Image.network(
                  "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/08/29/06/24/elephants-4438284__340.jpg",
                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                  //  height: 60,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
```

***Update:***
**Only Animating Specific container:**

```
List _height = List.generate(20, (i) => 60.0).toList();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      ),
//      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
//          child: Icon(Icons.edit),
//          onPressed: () {
////            setState(() {
////              _height = 120;
////            });
//          }),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 20,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return _buildCard(context, index);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCard(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0, vertical: 8.0),
      child: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
          color: Colors.teal,
          height: _height[index],
          width: 60.0,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(12.0),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12.0),
                ),
                child: Image.network(
                  "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/08/29/06/24/elephants-4438284__340.jpg",
                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                  //  height: 60,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _height[index] == 60
                        ? _height[index] = 120.0
                        : _height[index] = 60.0;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Maybe I wasn't very clear about it, Buy my problem was expand specific container when pressed , Not all the containers.

Comment: which specific container you want to do .? - mention it in code.

Comment: As you can see I've photo and icon button in every container in the list , When I pressed the Icon button I want  this specific container to expand

Comment: ok, so you mean instead of all 20 containers - you want to expand only one of it based on index.?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I meant

Comment: Done @Micro-Scope - Answer updated - click the icon - `Icons.ac_unit` will update only that container.